# Converting a C# function to equivalent SQL Function

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a c# function like shown below.

```
public double myFunction(byte[] hashA, byte[] hashB)
    {
        byte[] D = new byte[72];
        for (int i = 0; i < 72; i++)
        {
            D[i] = (byte)(hashA[i] ^ hashB[i]);
        }
        double bits = (double)72 * 8;
        double magic = //Snipped code using D
        double k = (magic / bits);
        return (100 - (100 * k)); ;
    }
```

I want to convert it to equivalent SQL Server function. I have written the function as shown below. However, I am stuck at converting the following line

```
 D[i] = (byte)(hashA[i] ^ hashB[i]);
```

MY SQL Function is as shown below:

```
CREATE function [dbo].[MyFunction](@hash1 binary(72), @hash2 binary(72))
returns int

AS
BEGIN 
    DECLARE  @dist float, @D binary(72)
     DECLARE @i INT
     DECLARE @bits float, @k float
      SET @i = 0
      SET @i = 0
     WHILE @i <= 72
    BEGIN
        SET @D[i] = CAST((@hash1[i] ^ @hash2[i]) AS BINARY)

        SET @i = @i + 1
            END

    END
```

Comment: What's the point of the `byte[] D...` if it has no use in the return value?

Comment: @pwnyexpress, Its a long procedure. I have written only the necessary code for clarity purpose. The value '1000' is actually derived from byte[] D.

Comment: Why do you want to move the code from C# to SQL server? Use each tool for what it is best for.

Comment: I updated the question to address pwny's question and remove confusion, feel free to rename the variable if you don't like it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this.

```
DECLARE @hash1Byte binary(1)
    DECLARE @hash2Byte binary(1)
    DECLARE @d binary(1)
    SET @i = 0
    WHILE @i < 72
    BEGIN
        SET @i = @i + 1

        set @hash1Byte = substring(@hash1, @i, 1)
        set @hash2Byte = substring(@hash2, @i, 1)
        set @d = @hash1Byte ^ @hash2Byte

    END
```